# PrimeFaces facebook, twitter requests

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I migrated my project from version 2.2 to the latest one 3.3.1 of Primefaces.

After successful migration, in every http request I see that browser sending request to facebook, twitter and download pictures from company website?

I don't have any reference regarding those web sites in my project and I did't have those requests in older version of Primeface. Also, I noticed that I have cookies related to those web sites created by my project.

How can I disable this option?